# How can i get the APDU for smart card?

Tags: android, smartcard, emv

Explanation: I am trying to read smart card using POS machine. I don't know anything to reading the card number and what is APDU? I have integrated an SDK for the android machine device and trying to read the card using icc classes which is provided in the SDK of machine.

I have lot of question regarding the APDU and transaction flow:

Q-1) Does APDU are same for all types of card?

Q-2) How APDU construct?

Q-3 From where to get the APDU which reading card?

I am using these APDU by default:

byte[] apdu_utf = {
            (byte)0x00, (byte) (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x59, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x53,
            (byte)0x59, (byte)0x53, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x31
    };

Follow below link to get help:

[Use APDU commands to get some information for a card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663460/use-apdu-commands-to-get-some-information-for-a-card?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Can anybody help me to solve out? Thank you

Comment: Your question is no specific, and this is not a place where you can find tutors. Start reading, understand the basics, come back when you get stuck somewhere. I recommend downloading specifications from EMVCo website , book1, 2,3,4. And read in the order 3, 4, 1,2.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are vast differences between APDUs for different cards. The general idea should become clear after studying ISO 7816-4, -8 and -9. To find out out, what is supported by your card (supported subset, additional proprietary commands, deviations, etc.), look into the operating manual of that specific card.

You may be required to sign a non-disclosure agreement for obtaining it, but anything else may result in wasting time.