# How to identify card number,expiry date, cvv, card holder name from from read record result

Tags: smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv

the following was the result I got from reading the record that contained card info of contactless card using nfc

["70", "73", "9f", "6c", "2", "0", "1", "9f", "62", "6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "e0", "0", "9f", "63", "6",

"0", "0", "0", "0", "1f", "80", "56", "32", "42", "35", "31", "39", "39", "31", "31", "30", "37", "37",

"35", "30", "35", "32", "33", "36", "35", "5e", "20", "2f", "5e", "32", "32", "30", "35", "32", "32",

"31", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30",

"30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "9f", "64", "1", "4", "9f", "65", "2", "1c", "0", "9f", "66", "2",

"3", "f0", "9f", "6b", "13", "**XX**", "**XX**", "**XX**", "**XX**", "**XX**", "**XX**", "**XX**", "**XX**", "d**Y**", "**YY**", "**Y**2", "21", "0",

"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "f", "9f", "67", "1", "4", "90", "0"]

*note: single values in the array are prefixed with 0 i.e "e" means "0e"*

By inspection I have been able to identify the card number which is marked out with **XX** and expiry date marked out with **Y**'s

But I want to get other info like cvv,card holder name

How am I to identify where these are. Because the card number and cvv was just by physical inspection.What values do I ought to look out for to find them.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Without substantial knowledge of the EMV specification, I have some doubts, that all information you desire is visible at the contactless interface at all. I would be surprised to see the  *card holder name* there at all, since I don't recognize it as  essential for the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

EMV follow TAG, length, value standard. You need to read bit level, understand and implement, or you will end up coding for each tag. Details on where you can find materials to read on it, [refer my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60799145/2251990).

Output of READ RECORD is formatted in a Template 70. Read more about it in EMV BOOKs. Download link is also included in the above link.

Just to see how the data is formatted, remove the double quotes and put your data here [here](https://paymentcardtools.com/emv-tlv-parser) if it is a test card.